# how can a read-only string literal be used as a pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers, string-literals

In C one can do this

`printf("%c", *("hello there"+7));`

which prints `h`

How can a read-only string literal like "hello there" be used almost like a pointer? How does this work exactly?

Comment: Because a string literal is an array, and an array can almost always be "used almost like a pointer".  Specifically, when you use an array (including a string literal) in an expression, the value you get is a pointer to the array's first element.

Comment: wait a minute, so the string literal "hello there" is an alias for the array it itself is stored in?

Comment: @programme3219873 Nearly bingo. It's an unnamed string literal.  "Alias" isn't quite right. It _**is**_ a string literal which consists of a `char` array with a `\0` at the end.

Comment: ok so just to conclude, the unnamed string literal implicitly decays to a pointer to the first element of the array which makes this all possible?

Comment: Yepp - exactly so.

Comment: You're welcome. To expand: `const char *foo = "hello there";` and then `*(foo + 7)` or simpler, `foo[7]`, would be easier to comprehend, but it has the same result. Naming entities often makes it easier to look at. That's one reason why "clever" constructs may actually have the opposite effect they were designed to have. Don't discourage people to refactor what you write.

Comment: @programme3219873, Detail: "hello there" is not _read-only_ - even though a good idea to treat it so  Attempting to write to it is _undefined behavior_ -  it might "work", not not.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'anonymous' string literals can be fun.

It's common to express dates with the appropriate ordinal suffix. (Eg "1st of May" or "25th of December".)

The following 'collapses' the 'Day of Month' value (1-31) down to values 0-3, then uses that value to index into a "segmented" string literal. This works!

```
// Folding DoM 'down' to use a compact array of suffixes.
i = DoM;
if( i > 20 ) i %= 10; // Change 21-99 to 0-9.
if( i >  3 ) i  =  0; // Every other one ends with "th"
//         0   1   2   3 
suffix = &"th\0st\0nd\0rd"[ i * 3 ];  // Acknowledge 3byte regions.
```

Answer (score 0):

A string literal is a character array (`char[]`) and is thus implicitly cast to a char pointer (`char *`) to the first element of the array.

Thus, in the example in the question (`"hello there"+7`), `7` is added to a pointer to the first character (`h`) giving a pointer to the 7th character (counting zero based) which also happens to be a `h` (the "h" in "there").

Notice that the pointer is to `char`, not `const char`. However, it is important to know that writing at the location pointed at by a string literal is undefined behavior which means that each compiler implementation is free to define its own behavior in that case. Depending on the compiler implementation, it may be impossible (the string literal may be stored in read-only memory), it may have unforeseen side-effects, it may change the string string literal without any side-effects or ... basically anything.

It is allowed for two identical or overlapping string literals such as "hello there" and "there" to share the same memory location. Hence, the following expressions may be either true or false depending on the compiler implementation:

```
  "hello" == "hello"
  "hello there" + 6 == "there"
```